# How to filter a list with common string and group to a new list

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a `List<String>` which consist of a json string. example below has 5 items in the list. Is there any simple way to extract common class (ex. Biology, Mathematics, History) from the list and group it and create a new List for all the common class.

```
{"name":"Alex","age":"31","class":"Biology","parents":{"father":"Robert","mother":"Mary"}}
{"name":"John","age":"34","class":"Mathematics","parents":{"father":"Remi","mother":"Maya"}}
{"name":"Rita","age":"27","class":"History","parents":{"father":"Shankar","mother":"Anita"}}
{"name":"Sonia","age":"27","class":"Biology","parents":{"father":"Mathew","mother":"Lucy"}}
{"name":"Caroline","age":"29","class":"Mathematics","parents":{"father":"David","mother":"Christine"}}
```

expected:

**List newList1**

```
{"name":"Alex","age":"31","class":"Biology","parents":{"father":"Robert","mother":"Mary"}}
{"name":"Sonia","age":"27","class":"Biology","parents":{"father":"Mathew","mother":"Lucy"}}
```

**List newList2**

```
{"name":"John","age":"34","class":"Mathematics","parents":{"father":"Remi","mother":"Maya"}
{"name":"Caroline","age":"29","class":"Mathematics","parents":{"father":"David","mother":"Christine"}}
```

**List newList3**

```
{"name":"Rita","age":"27","class":"History","parents":{"father":"Shankar","mother":"Anita"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a DTO representing your JSON structure (e.g. `class YourDTO`)
2. Use Jackson's ObjectMapper to parse your JSON string to instances of the Java class
3. Use Stream API and `groupingBy` collector to create a `Map<String, List<YourDTO>>`, by grouping on the Category of the parsed object
4. Assign the required categories to separate variables or call `.values()` on the map to get a `List<List<YourDTO>>`.

Comment: Your second step wouldn't work because input type is List<String> and I cannot create instance of object mapper unless I use for loop to iterate over each list item and then create object mapper instance with the DTO class

Comment: @SaddamHussainIH no, why would you need multiple ObjectMapper instances? Either loop over your inputs and call `om.readValue` for each value or call `readValue` with a `new TypeReference<List<YourDTO>>() {}`